# Redefining \mathop

Tags: math-mode, macros, math-operators

For the normal `\mathop` primitive, the extra space on the right side of the operator will not be displayed when it is followed by a parenthesis. For my own work, I am notating the operators after the input. That is, I write `(x)f` for `f(x)`, however, since the `\mathop` primitive isn't originally defined for this purpose, the thin space before the operator still shows up. Is there a way to redefine `\mathop` to fit better with this notation?

This is how `\mathop` is behaving. (Using `\ker` as an example)

[image]

```
$f \ker f$

$(f) \ker (f)$
```

This is how I want `\mathop` to behave.

[image]

Comment: luatex makes the spacing configurable but not other tex variants. probably simpler to define ker as `\mathrm{ker}\,`